# after adding an "overflow: Scroll" the hidden div that should show if hovered over an child div does not appear anymore

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a list of **divs**(**`childs`**) that **contains** an **item**(it's a **`shoppingcard`**) that should display more information if you hover over it. I've got it working but it is a list that can get more items than the div(the div is "fixed") can fit. So it needs an `overflow-x: auto;`. But when it has an `overflow-x` it does not show the menu anymore outside the div(parent). How can i make it appear outside?

my code, you can also see it on [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/4jfgL5gr/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="makerelative">            
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemContainer onHover">
            <a>input</a>
            <div class="popupMenu">
                    <button>button1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify more. You want it to appear outside what?

Comment: i guess he wants the menu to appear on left of the yellow div ( which he wants to be vertically scrollable )

Comment: the menu has to apear on the right side and it should have hover menus apear on the left side of the menu. as can be seen in my fidle code demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying many things i came to the anser that is you create an "overflow: auto;" it will not let anything appear on the outside of the **div** you specify it to. so to make it appear increase the size of your **div** and give the options a "max-width" now your **div** has free space. use "left: " or "right: " to set it at the right location and it will work!

thanks for all the help.

For all the people that want the code it's on [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mj5fj72f/).

Answer (score 0):

try to add `position: fixed;` to your popupMenu and position it-> this will make it appear

Comment: that means i have to hardcode every position that is possible.

Answer (score -2):

I Just cleaned up the code and used JS to print out a bunch of items.

Just take a look at the CSS and the div structure.

Good luck.

```js
var contents = "<div class=makerelative'>\
    <div class='ItemContainer'>\
      <a>input</a>\
      <div class='popupMenu'>\
       MORE INFO HERE THIS IS THE EXTRA WINDOW<br>\
        <button>button1</button>\
      </div>\
    </div>\
  </div>";
  
  var container = $("#container");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   container.append(contents);
  }
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.makerelative {
  position: relative;
}

.ItemContainer {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px dashed #000;
  background: #CCC;
}

.ItemContainer:hover {
  color: white;
  background: deepskyblue;
}


.ListContainer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.popupMenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -20;
  outline: 1px dashed #000;
  width: 150px;
}

.ItemContainer:hover .popupMenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: that is not the point. if i make the container fixed(what is should be) and add the scrollbar in the container it does not work anymore.